# How can I make my program not run in an endless loop once my mouse button is pressed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pynput

So I'm trying to make the program not run in an endless loop once pressed is true and check for when the mouse button is released and stop the while loop.

```
from pynput import mouse
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
import time
m = Controller()


def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    print('Pressed' if pressed else 'Released')

    while (pressed):
        m.move(0, 1)
        time.sleep(.001)

with mouse.Listener(
        on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: You can't do it that way.  Your event handler must execute something short and then return, otherwise `mouse.Listener` can't listen for more events.  What are you trying to do here?  Move the mouse while it is depressed?  You will have to use a timer for that.  The `on_click` handler can update a global state that your other thread monitors.

Comment: im trying to make it so that if my left mouse button is pressed down it moves the cursor down until left mouse is released

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.  Don't try to sleep for 1ms, you'll waste too many resources.

```
from pynput import mouse
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
import time
m = Controller()

mousedown = False


def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    global mousedown
    print('Pressed' if pressed else 'Released')
    mousedown = pressed

listener = mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click) 

while True:
    if mousedown:
        m.move( 0, 1 )
    time.sleep( 0.1 )
```